# How to reuse a closure function assigning it to a variable or constant in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures, reusability

I'm solving an exercise that is intended to use closures. You must create a function that returns a function that will store a value and, when you reuse it, add the new value to the saved one.

```
const firstValue = myFunction(3);
const secondValue = firstValue(4);
// result => 7
```

this is the code that I'm using to practice closures:

```
function addNumbers(num) {
    let storage = 0
    let n = num
    function adding(n) {
        storage += n;
        return storage
    }
    return adding(n)
}

let firstAttemp = addNumbers(4)
let secondAttemp = firstAttemp(3)

console.log(firstAttemp)
```

this throw an error "Uncaught TypeError: firstAttemp is not a function"

Comment: You're returning the output of calling `adding(n)`, not the actual `adding` function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @skara stated in their comment, `return adding(n)` returns the result of calling `adding` instead of returning the function so that it may be called later with `firstAttemp(3)`.

Unfortunately though it still doesn't work because you don't actually assign the value passed to `addNumber` to be added later.

```js
function addNumbers(num) {
  let storage = 0;
  let n = num;

  function adding(n) {
    storage += n;
    return storage;
  }
  return adding;
}

let firstAttemp = addNumbers(4);
let secondAttemp = firstAttemp(3);

console.log(firstAttemp);
console.log(secondAttemp); // 3!
```

You don't actually need to manually save the value of `num` to a variable as it is captured in the closure arround `adding` that is being returned.

```js
function addNumbers(num) {
  function adding(n) {
    return num + n;
    return storage;
  }
  return adding;
}

let firstAttemp = addNumbers(4);
let secondAttemp = firstAttemp(3);

console.log(secondAttemp); // 7
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const addNumbers = (a) => (b) => a + b
```

It's called currying, more details [here](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

P.S.
If you want to use `function` syntax, it will look like this:

```js
function addNumbers(a) {
  return function (b) {
    return a + b
  }
}
```